# How can I optimize the following SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now it is taking a long long time to run.

The query is:

```
select count(id), variety_id, name 
from tblItem 
where order_id IN (
    select order_id 
    from tblItem 
    where variety_id=4005 
    order by order_id DESC) 
AND variety_id != 4005 
GROUP BY variety_id 
order by count(id) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I have indexes on variety_id and order_id. I'm basically trying to build a recommendation engine. The query is looking for the top 5 items people buy when they also bought variety_id 4005. But like i said it takes way to long to run.

Does anyone have a way to optimize this query?

Comment: There's no point to using `ORDER BY` in the subquery -- either something is in the set or it isn't, the order doesn't matter. Hopefully MySQL ignores that clause.

Comment: Show your indexes, data types, and storage engine please.

Comment: Try using EXPLAIN and see, what execution plan was chosen. Maybe then You'll see some way to optimize it or maybe You'll see, that it cannot be optimized more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(t1.id), t1.variety_id, t1.name 
from tblItem t1
inner join tblItem t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.order_id and t2.variety_id = 4005
where t1.variety_id != 4005 
GROUP BY t1.variety_id, t1.name
ORDER BY count(t1.id) DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Works. Does this work simply because inner join is way more efficient?

Comment: Partly. Without context, I can't be sure that the join won't match more than one record on the right side for each on the left, and so I also had to change the GROUP BY to ensure accurate results. Removing the ORDER BY step in the derived table probably helped, too. The join could potentially match more than one recordAlso: for query tuning questions, I find it very helpful for people to see reported before and after results. If you can share that, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: I'm joining tlb lItem with itself here..order Id is not a unique field .. orders can have multiple items..so is the inner join the correct join here?  Results are this..the original query took 60 plus seconds. The new one runs instantly

Comment: Inner join is probably still okay, but you may want change the join to match on the entire primary key for the table, so that you are sure of a 1:1 join match.

Answer (score 2):

I've often found that MySQL optimizes `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` poorly, and `JOIN` works better; I've read that recent MySQL versions are better, so it may be version-dependent. Also, you should use `COUNT(*)` unless the column can be `NULL` and you need to ignore the null values in the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count, variety_id, name
FROM tblItem AS t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id
      FROM tblItem
      WHERE variety_id = 4005) AS t2
ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
WHERE t1.variety_id != 4005
GROUP BY variety_id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The subquery with `DISTINCT` is needed to prevent multiplying the counts by the number of matching rows in the cross-product.